# How to interpret Google Search Console URL Crawl Errors

Tags: url, google-search

We have a relatively large website and by looking at Google Search Console we have found a lot of strange errors. By lot, I mean 199 URLs give 404 reponse.

My problem is that I don't think these URLs can be found on any of our pages, even though we have a lot of dynamically generated content.

Because of this, **I wonder if these are URLs the crawler found or requests coming to our site**? Like `mysite.com/foobar`, which obviously would return 404.

Answer (score 0):

Google reports all backlinks to your website that deliver a 404 in the Google Search Console, no matter if there has ever been a webpage with that URL in the past.

When you click on an URL in the pages with an error list, a pop-up window will give you details. There is a tab "Linked from" listing all (external) links to that page.

(Some of the entries can be outdated. But if these links still exist, try to get them updated or set up redirects for them. The goal in the end is to improve the user experience.)